# redirect ALL urls from old site to index.php on new one with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

A couple questions, simply:

1. Is the .htaccess file generally stored in the public_html directory? I think so, no?
2. If I do not find such file, can I simply create it and upload it with FTP?

3 (most importantly). What is the code I need to redirect ALL URLS to ONE new URL, namely, http://www.newsite.com

Is it nothing more than `Redirect 301 / http://www.newsite.com/`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it nothing more than `Redirect 301 / http://www.newsite.com/`?

Correct, it is the only thing you need. It will redirect anything starting with `/` to the appropriate place in `http://www.newsite.com/`. Example:

You go to `http://oldsite.com/some/path/to/file.php`, you'll get redirected to `http://www.newsite.com/some/path/to/file.php`.

If you want everything to go simply to the document root of the new site, you can use a `RedirectMatch` instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 .* http://www.newsite.com/
```

So if you go to `http://oldsite.com/some/path/to/file.php`, you'll get redirected to `http://www.newsite.com/`

Not all apache installations come with mod_rewrite installed, if it's not installed you'll get a 500 server error if you attempt to use the rewrite engine. However, mod_alias is usually always installed.

Comment: +1 -Informative answer. so RedirectMatch is utilized by mod_alias whereas Redirect 301 is utilized by mod_rewrite?

Comment: @khanahk No, both is mod_alias. One redirects everything after the path (inclusive) the other doesn't. The other answer uses mod_rewrite and it's possible you don't have it loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Whether you can just upload .htaccess to public_html depends on the web host, but that will likely work.

Question 2: I would set up the redirect like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I'll also note, you might be able to just do "RewriteRule *" instead of "RewriteRule ^(.*)" in the beginning of the second line, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: I just uploaded a .htaccess file with those contents and got this: 'Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.' Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible mod_rewrite isn't enabled... not sure how to work around that. Did you try without "RewriteEngine On"? That might already be enabled?

Comment: doesn't seem to change it for me. I fixed the situation by editing redirect settings in the domain registrar control panel.